# Network issue with two WAPs fighting each other

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a network that has a DSL modem to ISP and is hardwired to a D-Link 4-port/wireless access point... I have wired RJ45 from that router to the garage 50ft away to another 4-port/wireless router... The SSID of the first is a name and the garage has a name as well... All works for the most part in the house and the garage as well but sometimes in the house I see the devices keep connecting to the WAP in the garage over the house WAP which is less then 10ft away and has more bars in strength???

I have been beating my head against the wall trying to fig what gives.

Comment: Have you considered using mesh networking? Mesh networking handles issues such as these.

Comment: never heard term until now.. just googled now for setup but most i see show nodes which look like specials devices and has two sources of internet... I have one dsl isp modem and two waps of which the wap that is hooked to the internet port of the first router, and the second router is hooked to the firt router port2  3 or 4 etc.. both have same password to access internet but most devices like ipads or laptops want to keep hooking to the second router in the garage... how does meshing control this issue??

Comment: things worked really well for several years but then I think I changed things up a bit and have never been able to get things as stable?? for the amount of device on network I guess I cant complain I guess, but it is abit annoying

Comment: The AP your devices won't stay connected to may be using a wireless channel that has too much interference. Try another channel.

Comment: You don’t have “WAPs”. You have routers that just happen to have WiFi built in as well and from your description are not hooked up right. If you had WAPs, you’d have a system that could handle true network roaming. You’d be better off getting rid of the routers and replacing them with a real mesh network system such as CloudTrax or Ubiquiti.

Comment: @Appleoddity According to the IEEE 802.11 standard, any device that publishes an 802.11 network is an Access Point (AP). So it doesn't matter if laymen call it a "WAP" or a "wireless router", when it comes to 802.11, it's an AP. It doesn't take any special equipment to handle true network roaming. Roaming is done by clients, not the network. Some proprietary solutions try to trick the clients into roaming in ways that the network wants, but they have to resort to dirty tricks, because the IEEE 802.11 standard puts the client, NOT the network, in charge of roaming decisions.

Answer (score 1):

The IEEE 802.11 standard (the official standard underlying Wi-Fi) leaves it up to wireless client implementations to decide how to roam between multiple APs publishing the same SSID (wireless network name). So if all your APs are publishing the exact same SSID with the exact same security type (hopefully WPA2-PSK AES-CCMP ONLY, nowadays; no more original WPA/TKIP) and passphrase, then your clients should tend to connect to the AP with the higher signal strength.

But if you have different APs publishing different SSIDs, the clients consider them different networks. Most client implementations let you create a ranked list of which SSIDs they should look for and connect to. This is usually called something like a "Preferred Networks List". So when your clients are within range of two APs publishing two separate SSIDs which are both in their preferred networks list, they will pick the one that's ranked higher in the list.

Your Question makes it sound like you're using two different SSIDs for the two networks, and your clients are choosing the SSID that you've ranked higher in their preferred networks list.

If you want your clients to join the AP with the best signal, make both APs publish the same network name (SSID) with the same security type and passphrase.